# How to list UTF encoded filenames in a given directory in CPP?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion

I'm trying to get all the files in a given directory, under Windows 10, using a CMake based CPP project (VS compiler).
I can't use boost or other libs.
I'm using the following function

```
        string search_path = "D:\\*.*";
        WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
        HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(search_path.c_str(), &fd);
        if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            do {
                // read all (real) files in current folder
                // , delete '!' read other 2 default folder . and ..
                if(! (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
                {
                    printf("%s - ", fd.cFileName);
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
                    {
                        printf("%02x", fd.cFileName[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            } while(::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
            ::FindClose(hFind);
        }
```

It works fine for ASCII filenames, but an arabic file shows up as

`???? ???? ?????.jpg - 3f3f3f3f203f3f3f3f203f3f3f3f3f2e6a706700746d6c0000696e646f77`

I welcome any kind of pointer.

Comment: Use `FindFirstFileW`

Comment: Did you remove the default Unicode define? The only explanation I can see for that. Which well, don't.

Comment: I specified "add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")" in CMakeLists. I'm using CLion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you could also try with standard library solution

```
for(auto& p: std::filesystem::directory_iterator("D:\\")) {
  std::wstring file_name = p.wstring();
}
```

Comment: Finally. Output shows 443A5C546573745C6286346276312062D6276416382062764462363362F2E6A7067, which is the expected result. Thank you, brother!

Comment: show the code you did with this answer, since I've got feeling you still do not understand the problem. This expected output looks like invalid. Note he proposed to use wide characters!

Comment: @MarekR yes, the correct output would be "628 634 627 631 20 62D 627 641 638 20 627 644 623 633 62F 2E 6A 70 67", i just printed it back to back (including D:\Test\).

Answer (score 3):

Problem is encoding set up on your system.
To make it work your system has to be configured to handle Arabic characters in single byte encoding. Windows do not use UTF-8.
Check [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page).

Other way is use wide characters API and `wchar_t`. In this case Windows uses `UCS-2` or `UTF-16` and it should work out of the box.

Also [must read](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).